Package not found after sourcing with ROS 2 Humble
I am building a package and receive the correct output that you would expect for a package:
Starting >>> controllers
Finished <<< controllers [7.45s]                     

Summary: 1 package finished [7.69s]

I open a new terminal, source my ROS 2 installation (/opt/ros/humble/setup.bash), source my package (install/setup.bash), and I try to run the only node that is in the package (pi_node) with the following command:
ros2 run controllers pi_node

But I receive the following error:
Package 'controllers' not found

Also, autocomplete is not working. I have been deleting my workspace and retrying, but there is nothing that solves the issue, and I don't know what else could be failing. My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(controllers)

find_package(Eigen3 3.4 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(turtlesim REQUIRED)

include_directories(include)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
    add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

add_executable(pi_node src/pi_node.cpp include/control/controller.hpp include/control/pi_controller.hpp)
ament_target_dependencies(pi_node rclcpp turtlesim geometry_msgs)
target_link_libraries(pi_node Eigen3::Eigen)

install(TARGETS
    pi_node
    DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

ament_package()

The content of my package.xml file is:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>controllers</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="pablo.arandarod@gmail.com">pablo</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>
  <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  <depend>std_msgs</depend>
  <depend>geometry_msgs</depend>
  <depend>turtlesim</depend>
  <export>
    <build_type>cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>


is your package listed when using the command
ros2 pkg list | grep controllers ?

@JakubIvan Nope

Please post your package.xml since e.g. ros2 run queries the ament index to find packages.

The best way to get help on this is to create a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so that everything is available for people to help you with.

Just added the package.xml content @Bi0T1N

Since you're creating a “ament CMake” package the build type should be <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>. More information about ament (and other build types) and its functionality can be found in the design article - Integrate arbitrary build systems. ament_cmake automatically writes to the ament resource index at build time and thus provides efficient access to information like the available packages, messages, etc at runtime.

@Bi0T1N this solved it! Thanks a lot! I can give you the bounty if you put it as an answer.

Since you want to create a “ament CMake” package (use of ament_cmake with ament_package() in CMakeLists.txt) you also need to set ament_cmake for build_type in the export section of the package.xml because defining cmake indicates a plain CMake package without all the automatic ament magic (it calls e.g. ament_index_register_resource for you).
More information about ament (and other build types) and its functionality can be found in the design article - Integrate arbitrary build systems. ament_cmake automatically writes to the ament resource index at build time and thus provides efficient access to information like the available packages, messages, etc at runtime.
Added my initial answer from above as requested so that this question can be marked as answered.

Solution from Bi0T1N's comment solved the problem. Build type was lacking in the package.xml.

Can you try sourcing the workspace once build is done and run the executable.

source install/setup.bash


Please re-read the post. There I indicate that I have sourced the workspace.

Can you try excluding headers in add_executable?
add_executable(pi_node src/pi_node.cpp)


The issue is not related to the compilation, since the compilation is successful.
